# meta_query works locally but not on live server

Tags: wp-query, meta-value, escaping

I'm filtering posts by author's last name initials. On my local server, the query runs beautifully, but when I push live, it doesn't. It doesn't find anything. Does it have anything to do with the way I'm escaping the custom field value?

```
$author = get_query_var('author-initials');

if (!empty($author)) {

    $initials = explode('-', $author);
    $value = array();

    foreach($initials as $initial) {
        $value[] = strtolower($initial);
        $value[] = strtoupper($initial);
    }

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'whitepaper_author',
        'value' => "\s[" . implode('', $value) . "]\w+$",
        'compare' => 'REGEXP'
    );
}

if (count($meta_query) > 1) {
    $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';
}

$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
```

Comment: I'm curious, but where is this code snippet? Where does the `$query` variable come from? Is this a `pre_get_posts` filter? Note that trying to filter/find posts by their post meta is extremely slow, and can bring powerful servers to their knees quickly. That you're trying to do a regular expression is even worse! Are you sure you wouldn't prefer a custom taxonomy named `whitepaper_author`? It could be as much as 10,000x faster and more scalable, running it on your local server is deceptive as you are the only person visiting that site and it has a full CPU to run the query

Comment: Maybe a stupid comment, but have you made sure the DB is exactly the same locally and live? Maybe there's just nothing to find.

Comment: The $query comes from an pre_get_posts action hook. I guess I'm not having problems with speed, but thanks for the advice. I'm just not getting the results I want from that meta_query array on the live server. I'm also running a tax_query array inside the same $query, and it finds posts based on the taxonomies I select.

Comment: @Pim Yeah, the DB is exactly the same. Does the problem have anything to do with the way I wrote those escaping sentences?

Comment: have you checked the collation?

Comment: @huraji yes, live collation is different from what I have on my local configuration. That's bad, right?

Comment: Well not always but you can try that. For experience I know that sometimes causes various troubles.

Comment: @huraji I tried but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where is `$query` defined?

Comment: @huraji the $query is defined in functions.php, pre_get_posts action.

Comment: Try a different approach on the query, I know it's weird but there might be something on your live server which you ignore. At this point you should try also a different way, just for saving some dev time.

Comment: @huraji do you know a better to do this? 'value' => "\s[" . implode('', $value) . "]\w+$",

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php?

Comment: @huraji yes, but it doesn't work. I think it has to do with WP Engine.

Comment: @GabrielH. yes I think that should be something server related. Ask them if they can support.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using  (blank space) instead of `\s` and `.` instead of `\w`

For further details on supported operators and characters please check this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html